# Table doesn't align negative numbers and positive numbers

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[b]%
\centering
\caption{determined \emph{hkl} indices and their corresponding.}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{MO}\\
\midrule
\emph{h} &\emph{k} &\emph{l} & (obs) & (Calc) & Difference\\
\hline

 0          & -1         & 0          & 10.3508       & 10.3893        & -0.0385    \\
 1          &  1         & 0          & 16.1424       & 16.167         & -0.0246    \\
 0          &  0         & 2          & 19.6878       & 19.7087        & -0.0209    \\
-1          & -1         & 2          & 22.4105       & 22.35          & 0.0605     \\
-3          & -1         & 1          & 31.6149       & 31.6054        & 0.0095     

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: In a formal tabular, you should use the same number of digits after the comma separator. You may then right adjust the column. I.e. 16.167 should become 16.1670, and 22.35 should become 22.3500. Negative numbers also line up if you right align.

Answer (score 3):

As you've "discovered", the `l` column type performs left-alignment of the column contents.

To align numbers on their respective (explicit or implicit) decimal markers, you could load the `siunitx` package and use its `S` column type -- see below -- or the `dcolumn` panckage and its `D` column type.

[image: WE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for "S" column type
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]%
\centering
\caption{determined \emph{hkl} indices and their corresponding \dots}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}
   S[table-format=-1.0]
   S[table-format=-1.0]
   S[table-format= 1.0]
   S[table-format= 2.4]
   S[table-format= 2.4]
   S[table-format=-1.4]
   @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{MO}}\\
\cmidrule{1-6} % \cmidrule is thinner than \midrule
{\emph{h}} & {\emph{k}} & {\emph{l}} & {(obs)} & {(Calc)} & {(Diff.)} \\
\midrule % not "\hline"
 0 & -1 & 0 & 10.3508 & 10.3893  & -0.0385 \\
 1 &  1 & 0 & 16.1424 & 16.167   & -0.0246 \\
 0 &  0 & 2 & 19.6878 & 19.7087  & -0.0209 \\
-1 & -1 & 2 & 22.4105 & 22.35    &  0.0605 \\
-3 & -1 & 1 & 31.6149 & 31.6054  &  0.0095 \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for cooperation